# Digital Root JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

Input: 635 
Output: 6+3+5 = 14   1+4=5

Input:65,536 
Output:2+5=7 (it works)

```js
function digital_root(n) {
  var z = n.toString();
  if (z.length == 2) {
    var x = parseInt(z[0]) + parseInt(z[1]);
    return x;
  } else if(z.length > 2){
    var i;
    for(i=0;i<=z.length;i++){
      var y = 0;
      y += parseInt(z[i]);
    }
    return y;
  }
}


console.log(digital_root(123)) // NaN
```

Someone can help me to change this code ? I'm a little bit confused about types of variables in return.

Comment: what do you need to change? it looks reasonable to me, what's not working?

Comment: Nice moustache :D The output is NaN for 123 for example.

Comment: you should move `var y = 0;` outside the loop. and this is not the correct method. you can achieve the same thing by dividing by 10.

Comment: I did it but it doesn't work too,output is NaN.I know but I tried to do it by myself

Comment: Why not do it the easy way: `n % 9 || 9`

Comment: you are using the length as the loop limit which is undefined change the loop's condition to `i < z.length`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems: you need to initialize `y` outside the loop where you increment it, and you should stop the loop **before** `i=z.length`; i.e. `i<z.length` instead of `i<=z.length`. This should work:

```
function digital_root(n) {
  var z = n.toString();
  if (z.length == 2) {
    var x = parseInt(z[0]) + parseInt(z[1]);
    return x;
  } else if(z.length > 2){
    var i;
    var y = 0;
    for(i=0;i<z.length;i++){
      y += parseInt(z[i]);
    }
    return y;
  }
 }
```

Comment: Well it returns 14 for 635,but I know what should I do know.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Beside the wrong check in the for loop (`<=` instead of `<`, the undefined item yields in `NaN` by converting `undefined` to a number), you could use a check for the length of the string and return the value if the length is one.

Otherwise add all digits (with an [unary plus `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) for converting the string to a number) and call the function again with the sum.

Some other annotations:

- declare all variables at top of the function,
- use for recursive call an exit condition, like this here for strings with length of one,
- prevent using `if () else if () ...` chains by using an early exit with `return` and take just an `if` in the further run without `else`.

```js
function digital_root(n) {
    var z = n.toString(),
        i,
        y = 0;

    if (z.length === 1) {
        return +z;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        y += +z[i];
    }
    return digital_root(y);
}

console.log(digital_root(635));   // 5
console.log(digital_root(65536)); // 7
```